# Java function pack(), JFrame size

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, pack

I'm having some problems with function pack(), as I know it should set size of JFrame to minimum.

Here is my masterpiece:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Okno extends JFrame{
        public Okno(String naslov){
                setTitle(naslov);
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
                Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();
                int sirina = d.width;
                int visina = d.height;
                setBounds(sirina/4,visina/4,sirina/2,visina/2);
        }
}
public class Pretvori{
        public static class Plosca extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
                JTextField vnesiC , izracunajF;
                protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                        super.paintComponent(g);

                        vnesiC = new JTextField(8);
                        add(vnesiC);

                        add(new JLabel("\u00b0C"));

                        JButton pretvori = new JButton(" = ");
                        add(pretvori);
                        pretvori.addActionListener(this);

                        izracunajF = new JTextField(8);
                        izracunajF.setEditable(false);
                        add(izracunajF = new JTextField(8));

                        add(new JLabel("F"));
                }
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        String c = vnesiC.getText();
                        Double dc = Double.parseDouble(c);
                        Double df = 1.80 * dc + 32.0;
                        String f = String.format("%f", df);
                        izracunajF.setText(f);
                }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
                Okno okno = new Okno("Pretvornik");
                okno.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                Plosca p = new Plosca();
                okno.add(p);
                okno.pack();
                okno.setResizable(false);
                okno.setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

Download link: http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=kGkpCrHe

And I am sorry for bad language.

Answer (score 3):

No, `pack` sizes the frame to its contents preferred size (based on the requirements of the layout managers), but since your `Plosca` doesn't have a preferred size, it's returning `0x0`, therefore your frame thinks the preferred size is `0x0`

This...

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        vnesiC = new JTextField(8);
        add(vnesiC);

        add(new JLabel("\u00b0C"));

        JButton pretvori = new JButton(" = ");
        add(pretvori);
        pretvori.addActionListener(this);

        izracunajF = new JTextField(8);
        izracunajF.setEditable(false);
        add(izracunajF = new JTextField(8));

        add(new JLabel("F"));
}
```

isn't how you should prepare your UI, `paintComponent` is used for performing custom painting, not adding to or changing the UI.

Instead, you should start adding your components from within the constructor

```
public Plosca() {
        vnesiC = new JTextField(8);
        add(vnesiC);

        add(new JLabel("\u00b0C"));

        JButton pretvori = new JButton(" = ");
        add(pretvori);
        pretvori.addActionListener(this);

        izracunajF = new JTextField(8);
        izracunajF.setEditable(false);
        add(izracunajF = new JTextField(8));

        add(new JLabel("F"));
}
```

Take a look at [How to create a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more details...

Answer (score 3):

One big problem is that you are adding components to your `Plosca` instance during each call to `paintComponent`. You should add your components in a `Plosca` constructor instead. Then when you call `pack()` it will have components so its preferred size won't be so small.

```
public static class Plosca extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    JTextField vnesiC , izracunajF;
    public Plosca() {
        vnesiC = new JTextField(8);
        add(vnesiC);

        add(new JLabel("\u00b0C"));

        JButton pretvori = new JButton(" = ");
        add(pretvori);
        pretvori.addActionListener(this);

        izracunajF = new JTextField(8);
        izracunajF.setEditable(false);
        add(izracunajF = new JTextField(8));

        add(new JLabel("F"));
    }

    // do not need paintComponent()

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        . . .
    }
}
```